# Ошибки во всплывающей подсказке, разъясняющей смысл «общих» ответов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

При наведении курсора на слово «общий» ниже поля ввода ответа:

[image: Общий ответ]

*Обязательно:*

- `Однако, голосование` → `Однако голосование` . «Однако» здесь не выступает в роли вводного слова, а эквивалентен союзу «но».
- `не возможно` → `невозможно`.

*Опционально:*

- `его сможет редактировать` → `ответ сможет редактировать`. Перед «его» стоят 2 слова в мужском роде, «ответ» и «падеж», причём «порог» позже.
- `принесет` → `принесёт`.

Comment: Ещё «Вам» → «вам»